How to Open gnome-terminal from mobaxterm x server
I have ubuntu 24.04 desktop installed on my office desktop box. I regularly access it from home using my windows pc. I do that by opening a mobaxterm and then ssh to my office-box .......This all goes well. I am even able to run xeyes on the office box and that is displayed well on my windows machine screen..No problem till here.
Encouraged with this, I tried to open gnome-terminal from command line in mobaxterm.... however it does not do anything. I did search internet for this and did try many solutions like dbus-launch and all. ... with no success.
Please let me know 1.If this is really possible. and 2. If yes, how can I make it possible.
Thanks

Yesterday I tried this command from home
1 dbus-launch gnome-terminal
2 dbus-launch gnome-terminal --disable-factor
It did not open the terminals on my windows pc ... as I was expecting.... But today when I came to office and logged in to desktop directly ... I see that all those terminals are opened there......................So something is missing ... please let me know how to proceed.
